# How to formally define this type of continuity of a function in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, continuity, classical-mechanics

A function on $\mathbb R^n$ (to $\mathbb R^1$) is say $C^2$ differentiable / (continuous) on $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$.

In (the neighborhood of) point $0$ it is ($C^0$) continuous and has a **finite** derivative in any radial direction.

(*It looks like a generalized regular cone there with its apex at point $0$.*)

How to define this type of partial continuity in more precise and formal math terms?

What type of a point is this point $0$ here?

(*It may seem like a kind of a generalization of a critical point of a function... Especially if we add some nice features of our function $f$ like positiveness of its radial gradient $(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})>0$ and maybe even its radial convexity, positiveness of its Hessian $(x\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial x}x)>0$,  for $\forall x$ on $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$.*)

Thank you very much for education.

Comment: Perhaps Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: +1 Thank you, Anthony. This will work. I will write: "_a function is $C^2$ continuous on $R^n\setminus0$ and Lipschitz continuous at point $0$ 
 (has limited derivatives in any radial direction at origin)_". ...Yet do not feel comfortable without this clarification.

Comment: And now another question arises: _Can such a function be always presented as a sum of a $C^2$ continuous on $R^n$ and а $C^2$ continuous on $R^n∖0$ multilinear (homogeneous of degree 1) functions?_

Comment: Another possible option? Can the following also be the answer for my first question?: _the function is $C^2$ continuous on $R^n∖0$ and uniformly continuous in a closed neighborhood of point $0$_ ?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis. Sorry, did not reference you correctly before.

Comment: $\sqrt{|x|}$ is uniformly continuous but has unbounded derivative.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis. See, Thank you.